# How do I add a hover element to multiple elements at once?

Tags: html, css

Alright so I'm coding this website for a class and I want to have it so that every time you hover over the image or text the image changes to a filled image instead of a stroke based and the text inverts from blue on a white background to white on a blue background. I want it to be so that if you hover over either of these elements, all the text and image change at the same time. [inactive state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmbow.png)
[active state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4o1K.png)

Here's my code:

```css
.exhibition {
  margin-left: %;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
  float: left;
}
.exhibition img {
  width: 180px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.exhibition b {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.exhibition i {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.exhibition p {
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
h1.suit a {
  display: block;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  background-image: url(images/icons/suit_stroke_large.png);
  text-indent: -99999px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  float: left;
}
h1.suit a:hover {
  background-image: url(images/icons/suit_fill_large.png);
  -webkit-transition: background 150ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background 150ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: background 150ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: background 150ms ease-in-out;
  transition: background 150ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="exhibition">
  <h1 class="suit"><a href="#">Suit Icon</a></h1>
  <p>
    <b class="lorem">Gilbert &amp; George: The Early Years</b>
    <br>
    <i class="lorem">May 9 - September 27, 2015</i>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Would you be ok with using JavaScript to do this?

Comment: If I could do it using CSS that would be nice, since it's a pretty basic class haha. But if I have to do Java I can.

Comment: Do you mean that if the user hovers the h1 or p the background image should change?

Comment: Right now if you hover over the icon, it changes to a filled icon. I want it to be that when you hover over the icon, the icon changes, and the text changes as well.

Answer (score 0):

To do this without using JavaScript, you would use :hover on the parent of the two elements. If the parent has other children that you don't want to trigger the :hover effects, then you would need to move them up a level or add another element such as a div to hold the two elements.

Then you could do something like:

```css
#parent #child1 {
    color: black;
}
#parent:hover #child1 {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

#parent #child2 {
    background-image: url("image1.jpg");
}
#parent:hover #child2 {
    background-image: url("image2.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the hover to `.exhibition` instead of `h1.suit a`. So it will be look something like this `.exhibition:hover h1.suit a`. For applying background and color for text (`b` and `i`), you can apply styles like this:

```
.exhibition:hover p, .exhibition:hover b, .exhibition:hover i {
    background-color: #006;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k7moorthi/ay7x8zgo/1/

Hope this will help you.